# Native repl command to load a single function from a source file?

Tags: clojure

All the main editors do this - send a single form in a source file to a connected repl. Is there a way to do this in a minimal setup? i.e. just a non-clojure aware editor plus a repl in the terminal.

e.g. 
`(load myfile.clj <myfunction>)`

I see there is [`load-string`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/load-string) as well as [`load-file`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/load-file) but no `load-function`.

Comment: I wonder how the editors do it when they send forms to the nrepl.  Actually one could see how to implement this, opening the file, scanning for function name, loading that form with `load-string`. Does this already exist somewhere?

Comment: The editors just send the form. If you want to investigate further, i'd start with one of the many plugins/editor integrations out there.  e.g. vim-fireplace can send a inner form, outermost form, by default. but you can send whatever you want. It basically picks the right namespace for you and evals "text". As for your question afaik there is no build in feature like this and given, that functions might depend on others, this might just be error prone (it's easier to run a require/reload based workflow).

Comment: load-string can be used to load a function as well, or any piece of valid Clojure code in fact. That said, something like nRepl is more complicated, you connect to it through a socket, and there is a wire protocol for sending it data for it to load and evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this right the editor selects all the text in the buffer and sends it to the REPL:

https://github.com/nasser/Socket/blob/master/commands.py#L120